# How can Docky, AWN, Cairo Dock and Unity be compared?

Tags: unity, docky, cairo-dock, awn

It would be very nice to see a comparison between features, icons and usability.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

*I will try to be impartial and objective. Help and suggestions are welcome ;-).*

**I'm very grateful for the important contributions of these buddies:

[Alaukik](https://askubuntu.com/users/5149/alaukik), [Kaustubh P](https://askubuntu.com/users/3778/kaustubh-p), [Uri Herrera](https://askubuntu.com/users/4203/uri-herrera) and [Mandy](https://askubuntu.com/users/15726/mandy).**

*First* of all, the question is tricky. Putting all this together may lead someone to think of Unity as a Dock, which it is not. Actually, it is a [User Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface) (see [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/FilingBugsthis) as reference to this affirmation and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dock_(computing)) for the definition of a Dock).

*Second:* the Unity [Launcher can't be moved from left edge](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/12/ubuntu-unity-launcher-wont-be-moveable).

To make this answer be more suitable, I will focus on features that are common to all and on those which are (at least to me) most desired.

---

---

## **Applications Menu**

*This is more easily answered with images:*

**Unity:**

[image]

[image]

**Cairo Dock:**

[image]
_

**AWN:**

*AWN own menu:*

[image]

*YAMA (has "Places" and bigger icons):*

[image]

*I wasn't able to find this feature for Docky but maybe it has it.*

---

---

## **Workspace Switcher**

**Unity:**
*You can't preview the workspaces from the Launcher:*
[image]

*But when you click on the icon, you will see:*
[image]

**Docky:**
*No preview:*
[image]

**AWN:**
[image]

**Cairo Dock:**
[image]

---

---

## **Notification Area**

**Unity:**
[image]

**AWN:**
[image]

**Cairo Dock:**
[image]

*I wasn't able to find this feature for Docky but maybe it has it.*

---

---

## **Monitoring:**

***Battery***

**Unity:**

[image]

**Docky:**

[image]

**AWN:**

[image]

**Cairo Dock:**

[image]

---

***Processor***

**Unity:**

[image]

and

[image]
*obs.: check [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/list-of-application-indicators) to see how to install this and others indicators.*
*Specifically for this indicator:* `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-multiload/stable-daily && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload && indicator-multiload`

**Docky:**

[image]

**AWN:**

[image]

**Cairo Dock:**

[image]

---

***RAM***

**Unity:**

[image]

**Docky:**

[image]

**AWN:**

[image]

**Cairo Dock:**

[image]

---

***Internet Connection***

**Unity:**

[image]

**Docky:**

[image]

**AWN:**

[image]

**Cairo Dock:**

[image]

---

***Hard Disk***

**Unity:**

[image]

**AWN:**

[image]

**Cairo Dock:**

[image]

*I wasn't able to find this feature for Docky but maybe it has it.*

---

***Dropbox***

**Unity:**

[image]

**AWN:**

[image]

**Cairo Dock:**

[image]

*I wasn't able to find this feature for Docky but maybe it has it.*

---

---

## **Weather**

**Unity:**

[image]
*Click [here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/indicator-weather) to install.*

**Docky:**
[image]

**AWN:**
[image]

**Cairo Dock:**
[image]

---

---

## **Date and Clock**

**Unity:**

[image]

**Docky:**

[image]
*When you click on it:*
[image]

**AWN:**

[image]

**Cairo Dock:**

[image]

---

---

## **Clipboard**

**Unity:**

[image]

**Docky:**

[image]

**Cairo Dock:**

[image]

*I wasn't able to find this feature for Docky but maybe it has it.*

---

---

## **Some extra features**

**Unity:** When you drag an app to the launcher it lights up the apps that can open it .

[image]

**Docky:**
[image]

**AWN:**
*This applet shows items related to what you are doing*
[image]

**Cairo Dock:**
*It is very beautiful and has lots of visual effects and configurations. Let's see some:*
*Sub folders*
[image]

*Widgets*
[image]

*Recent Events*
[image]

---

---

## **Lightness on system**

*On average, this is what* `top` *shows me for processor* (P) *and memory* (M) *usage:*

**Unity:**
P: 1 M: 0.4

[image]

**Docky:**
P: 1-2 M: 1.2

[image]

**AWN:**
P: 0 M: 0.3

[image]

**Cairo Dock:**
P: 0-1 M: 1.5

[image]

---

---

## Final Overview

**Unity:**
[image]

**Docky:**
[image]

[image]

**AWN:**

[image]

[image]

**Cairo Dock:**
[image]

[image]

---

---

## **Websites**

**Unity:** [unity.ubuntu.com](http://unity.ubuntu.com/about/)

**Docky:** [www.go-docky.com](http://www.go-docky.com)

**AWN:** [awn-project.org](http://awn-project.org/about/)

**Cairo Dock:**  [glx-dock.org](http://glx-dock.org/)

---

---

## **Installation**

**Unity:** It comes with Ubuntu 11.04 and later.

**Docky:** [docky](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/docky)

**AWN:**  [avant-window-navigator](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/avant-window-navigator) (I would suggest you also install [awn-applets-all](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/awn-applets-all))

**Cairo Dock:**  [cairo-dock](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/cairo-dock)

Comment: what do you mean AWN doesn't have an application menu , it has like 5.

AWN own menu, YAMA, cairo-menu, cardapio's, gnomenu..etc. and im pretty sure docky has application menu's too.

Comment: Thank you very much for this tip. I couldn't find it before.

Comment: Awn has an applet to host an indicator area. All the indicator will work there the same way that they do in Unity.

Comment: This is probably one of the most detailed answers I have ever seen on this site. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

No further comments or posts yet? Issue discussed in Distrowatch now:
http://distrowatch.com/weekly.php?issue=20130304#comments

Not sure why you defend Unity as NOT being a very inflexible, irresponsible taskbar. Unity can be used along with AWN, Docky, etc. It can be removed completely, if needed from any Unity based distro, if needed (above url in Distrowatch):

"8 • Re: 7 rolling releases (by hobbitland on 2013-03-04 12:48:17 GMT from United Kingdom)
 I've stayed with Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS but with Gnome 3 fallback and will move to XFCE for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I don't like rolling release as I heavilly remaster Ubuntu 12.04.2 with unity removed and gnome 3 fallback included plus lots of other tweaks."

My up-to-date Mint-KDE & Netrunner can emulate all of the above, and more:
Unity, Docky, Awn, Windows7, IOS, Cairo, Gnome, Mate, Cinnamon, etc - but not E17, which is too confusingly complex for a novice to modify atm.

Your survey neglect XFCE-based distros, that have seemingly unlimited taskbars on the 4 sides, intellihide, resizable, etc.

All the smaller taskbars (Docky, etc) can emulate the power-hungry bigger brothers by adding more apps; Compiz, etc. Not sure why you seem ignorant of this.

The so-mentioned deficits of Docky come from your unfair exploration of Docky, versus your biased explorations favoring Unity. Docky allows easy removal, adding, ordering, re-sizing of its icons better than almost any other taskbars, including Unity. If you need cubic or wallpapers of your desktops, just add the apps that allow this, such as Compiz or Cairo.

Personally I favor XFCE for fast, light distros on slow or simple setups, plus add-on apps (Compiz, etc) if needed. Independent bench tests suggest that I use the latest versions of KDE now for CPU, GPU, memory & resource savings. Hence my current uses of Netrunner & Mint-KDE on my multi-booting i7, 8GB DDR3 pc.

Chief Information Officer (Retired 1984), Australian Capital Territory

Answer (score 0):

Stacks for Docky: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/06/stacks-for-docky-looks-like-a-dream-works-like-one-too/

Read also precautions...