# Is there a Gnome applet similar to the Windows 7 dock with ungroup option?

Tags: software-recommendation, gnome-panel, dockbarx, panel-applets

I'm looking for taskbar that works similar to the one found in win7 and it's not unity:)
Dockbarx is very close to what I'm looking for but it does not have ungroup option.

Is there any gnome applet (or something?) that works like dockbarx but has the ungroup option?

**EDIT**

How does win7 taskbar works:

All open windows are presented as icons. You can add title to these icons but there is no text in default view, just icons - which is fine.
You can pin those programs so that they stay on the taskbar even if you close the program.
If the program is pinned it behaves like a placeholder for itself.

**For example** if you would like to open firefox, you just lick on the firefox icon and then it brings the current instance of firefox program **or** run a new instance if firefox is not running.
So if I click on the icon, the program is brought back (if it's running) or it's executed (if it's not running).

**Dockbarx works exactly like that except it cannot ungroup windows.** 
Nowadays in the age of webapps lack of this functionality is very big disadvantage. For example I have always opened chrome browser and gmail app (as a chrome app opened on gmail.com) and many other webapps as a chrome apps (command: chrome --app=http://www.example.com). Dockbarx groups them all into one icon because all of those are chrome instances. The author of dockbarx stated plainly that "ungroup" functionality will never be implemented in dockbarx so i ask if there is any gnome applet that works just like dockbarx but has ungroup option.

Comment: May you explain how does the taskbar of Windows 7 works?

Comment: Also here is some docks: http://askubuntu.com/questions/40878/how-can-docky-awn-cairo-dock-and-unity-be-compared

Comment: @desgua: It looks like he is looking for a gnome-applet, not a stand alone dock to me.

Comment: gnome applet would be best but stand alone software is also a good solution.

Comment: At Ubuntu Forum there are a setting configuration reported to work: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9925822 Besides that, I suspect Cairo-Dock and AWN can do this too, but I will investigate later when I get home.

Comment: Also there is a bug reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/dockbar/+bug/681376

Answer (score 1):

AWM allows it.
Right click to open setting, then click on task manager and then click on group/ungroup option.

Cairo, I haven't found it yet.
Not being able to work with ungrouped windows made leave unity.
Ungroup windows is a requirement when you really work with linux, when it is not a leisure, like when you use osx to work and then have fun with linux.

I've lost more than 3 man days to see that there was a stupid will to prevent users from chossing to group or ungroup windows. This is a considerable regression.

Comment: AWM? Do you mean AWN?