# Which theme or linux distro is this?

Tags: themes

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPSIA.png]

Which linux theme has been used in this picture, please help out ?

Comment: Why don't you ask Naveen Kumarasinghe? https://plus.google.com/+NaveenKumarasinghe/posts/AHuhA1ZFYt3 Must be him :) But it looks like the elementary dark (see http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/02/new-gtk3-and-gnome-shell-themes.html )

Comment: And a docking program and an icon pack. The docking program you can choose [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40878/how-can-docky-awn-cairo-dock-and-unity-be-compared), Icon packs from [Gnome-look](http://gnome-look.org/?xcontentmode=121)

Comment: tried to ask Naveen Kumar but I don't have enough reputation to make comments. Anyway thanks to both of you for helping me out :)